# Javascript: Image to Base64?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way how to encode a png/jpeg/gif image to base64 using Javascript (can't use canvas toDataURL)? Thank you.

Comment: You might look here: [#246801](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use the canvas API, then you can't.

Not unless it does a loopback with the server which returns the base64 encoded image.